# SearchView TextSize

Tags: android

I have the following `SearchView` implementation in the `xml`, the text entry has been cut from the top as shown in the below image. No matter what `textSize` I am putting, nothing changes.

```
 <SearchView
    android:id="@+id/search_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textSize="12sp"/>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The textsize of search view text is set using `AutoCompleteTextView` style.
You have to override above style to change the text size.

1) Add below in your main app theme

```
  <item name="android:autoCompleteTextViewStyle">@style/AppAutoTextCompleteStyle</item>
```

2) Define new `AutoTextCompleteStyle` as below. Provide your desired textsize in the style.

```
<style name="AppAutoTextCompleteStyle" parent="Base.V7.Widget.AppCompat.AutoCompleteTextView">
        <item name="android:textSize">16dp</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding `android:layout_margin="10dp"` and `android:padding="10dp"`.

UPDATE: Best way to implement android search interface : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html